# standard error of the median survival time using r

Tags: r, survival, standard-error, median, approximation

I would like to find the standard error of the median survival time and do some approximation to estimate the density function around the median survival time according to equation (5) of this:  http://www.med.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/hanley/c609/material/KaplanMeierEstimator.pdf
Is it possible to do it in R? If so, can you give me some example r code for this?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Would it suffice to just have a CI for the median? This is easily done and is a straightforward bit of R code. You might guess there are many possible formulations for the median, its standard error, and the scale it's calculated on - `survfit` uses some default settings, has some other implementations, but is generally an open problem.